# Object has no attribute 'setattr' when using pytest monkeypatch fixture

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest, monkeypatching

I have this dummy test code:

```
import pytest
from unittest.mock import Mock, create_autospec, call, ANY
from my_classes import MyClass2, MyClass1
import my_classes


class TestMyClass:

    def test_calc(monkeypatch):
        mocked_calc= Mock(return_value=54)
        monkeypatch.setattr(MyClass1,'calc1',mocked_calc)

        service_two = MyClass2(1,"test")
        assert service_two.calc(3,1)== 54

        assert mocked_calc.assert_called_once_with(3,1)
```

and when I run it with `pytest` i get this error `AttributeError: 'TestMyClass' object has no attribute 'setattr'`. Is the problem that I dont tell pytest to use the `monkeypatch` fixture or is it always loaded anyway? If that is not it why doesnt it work?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do as the code seems incomplete and overly complex to demonstrate the issue.  That being said, your error indicates that your `test_calc` is being called as a method (rather than a function) so you might consider adding `self` as a first argument (e.g. `def test_calc(self, monkeypatch)`).  [This is standard for tests-in-classes in pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/getting-started.html#group-multiple-tests-in-a-class). No idea whether it'll solve your issue, but it seems an issue itself.

Comment: @jedwards ok the missing self argument was causing the error.  What I am trying to figure out with this example is whether I can assert that a mocked method (object) was called with a specific argument. BUT I only know the value of one of the arguments. For example in the example above I wish to see if the value of the `multiplier` argument was equal to `3` even if I dont know the values of the other arguments (there is a second string argument for example to which I pass the value "test" but I pretend that I dont know that in my assertion.

Comment: Okay, sounds reasonable -- how are MyClass1 and MyClass2 related, if at all?  Is `MyClass1.calc1` supposed to return the same thing as `MyClass2.calc`?